# React - Using react to show Error and Positive Alerts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm fairly new to react and trying to get my head around hooks. I have the following issue. I've tried everything I can think of and have read until I have eventually posted on here.

**Issue:** When I submit my form, it's always returning a positive alert. When I know it's failing as I console log the Axios error.

My code is as follows:

```
const ContactPage = () => {
  const [weHavError, setWeHavError] = useState({});
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const AlertElement = (weHavError) => {
    console.log(weHavError);

    const alertMessage =
      "Thank you. Your contact information was submitted successfully.";
    const alertColour = "success";
    const alertIcon = "fa-check-circle";
    console.log("Things look good");

    if (weHavError.props.name) {
      const alertMessage =
        "We are sorry there was an error in submitting your information. Please try again later";
      const alertColour = "danger";
      const alertIcon = "fa-times-circle";
      console.log("There was an error");
    }

    return (
      <>
        <MDBAlert
          key="1"
          color={alertColour}
          autohide
          width={350}
          position="top-center"
          offset={50}
          delay={3500}
          appendToBody
          show={visibility}

          // onClick={() => toggleShowAlert}
        >
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div className="p-0">
              <i className={`fas ${alertIcon} me-3`}></i>
            </div>
            <div className="p-0">{alertMessage}</div>
            <div className="">
              <MDBBtn
                id="alertButt"
                className="btn-close"
                noRipple
                outline
                color="none"
                onClick={toggleShowAlert}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </MDBAlert>
      </>
    );
  };
```

I call it with the following:

```
const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/", {
        values,
      });
      toggleShowAlert();
      console.log("This shows if SUCCESS");
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    } catch (e) {
      setWeHavError(e); 
      toggleShowAlert(weHavError); 
    }
  };
    const toggleShowAlert = async (weHavError) => {
        setVisibility(!visibility);
      };
```

The console shows

```
Things look good
contact.page.component.jsx:47 There was an error
react_devtools_backend.js:2709 {props: AxiosError}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have helped if you had the entire component and calling/container component code here. With what I see, the issue is with the usage of constants and sequencing. Here is a suggestion, see if it works for you.

```
const ContactPage = () => {
const [weHavError, setWeHavError] = useState({});
const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false);

const AlertElement = (weHavError) => {
console.log(weHavError);

let alertMessage =
  "Thank you. Your contact information was submitted successfully.";
let alertColour = "success";
let alertIcon = "fa-check-circle";

if (weHavError.props.name) {
  alertMessage =
    "We are sorry there was an error in submitting your information. Please try again later";
  alertColour = "danger";
  alertIcon = "fa-times-circle";
  console.log("There was an error");
}else{
    console.log("Things look good");
}

return (
  <>
    <MDBAlert
      key="1"
      color={alertColour}
      autohide
      width={350}
      position="top-center"
      offset={50}
      delay={3500}
      appendToBody
      show={visibility}

      // onClick={() => toggleShowAlert}
    >
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div className="p-0">
          <i className={`fas ${alertIcon} me-3`}></i>
        </div>
        <div className="p-0">{alertMessage}</div>
        <div className="">
          <MDBBtn
            id="alertButt"
            className="btn-close"
            noRipple
            outline
            color="none"
            onClick={toggleShowAlert}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </MDBAlert>
  </>
);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked exactly how I expected it to work. I've been battling with it for a whole day and was close, but I just couldn't get it to work right! 
Thanks again